# Find inputs to a function which break the postcondition on the output

Tags: c, testing, formal-verification, software-quality, post-conditions

I have a function in a programming language, e.g. C. I require the output of the function to meet a certain condition. If there is some input to this function for which the output does not meet the required condition, I need to find any such exact input.

I need to do this in general, but for rather simple functions, e.g. the number of the loops is fixed and does not depend on the input. Another requirement is that I need to do this very fast. I found that CBMC tool [https://www.cprover.org/cbmc/] may help me, but I am not sure how to use it. I also welcome solutions which convert the problem into the CNF formula (but I still need to retrieve the counterexample input).

An example of the function:

```
int function(int n) {
    int m = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        m += n*i;
    }
    int output = m % 11;
    return output;
}
// POSTCONDITION: require the output < 10 for all inputs
// VERIFICATION: this is not true, the counterexample is the input n=9.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to use that tool? How to solve this particular example? What?

Comment: Solving my example with CBMC tool should be sufficient. But I welcome other solutions too. A solution should be easy to adapt to different functions.

Comment: `n=10` isn't a counterexample for the above function's postcondition. `n=9` is.

Comment: @IanAbbott Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple function with no loops at all:

```
bool function (int a, int b, int c)
{
   bool answer = a*a*a + b*b*b + c*c*c != 42;
   // POSTCONDITION: require answer==true
}
```

It took a few hundred computer-years (or, in real time, a couple of weeks on a 500,000-strong grid of PCs) to discover that there is a [counterexample](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.01209.pdf) (pdf):

> (−80538738812075974)<sup>3</sup> + 80435758145817515<sup>3</sup> + 12602123297335631<sup>3</sup> = 42

A program that can do that very fast is a very, very good program indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course, I understand computational complexity limits. What I refer to when saying that I need something fast is that the program should be reasonably smart and optimized. So for example, a solution in Python that goes over every possible input is unacceptable.

Comment: So what should the program you are looking for do with this function?

Comment: For many functions we do not know anything smarter than just trying all the possibilities. But for many other problems which may seem computationally heavy at first, there are some smart heuristic algorithms which even though in the worst case are expected to run in the exponential number of steps, on average they would still manage to find the solution within the polynomial time.

I am looking for a solution could work in a smart way for many functions, but I understand I cannot expect it would work for all.

Comment: BTW many open math problems were solved with some clever SAT solvers:
http://cs-svr1.swan.ac.uk/~csoliver/papers.html#Boise2017